# Cookie sent by API with different domain is not set

Tags: php, laravel, cookies, csrf

So, my API(laravel) runs on for example `https://api.example.com` and on client side, my site runs on `http://127.0.0.1:3000`. The API sends the following cookie,

`set-cookie: XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI6IkVRSjcyYzBoVzRTazQ4RWJjK0JSd2c9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiT20yb3AwZk1HemloaUl2MFZZdkUyUVM3Z3pXc3B0QXpiUEZPUEJIWElJYjRHamtlZ3d5NU5yb3doWmQ4ZXNBb1g0eTFiZXliRlFmWkN1SjVRMVFaM3pXK2x0MTMyK1MwTnp3cVZFSksvaVlJdGdLNGpKZXVrR3lITTRPU2VYNWgiLCJtYWMiOiI0MGU3NmEzYmI2NjY3MTkwNTNlMDQ2ZWRiNjVmNzdmYzA1MTMzOWE0NjA0YzAxYzBjZTczNzI4MDljOThhYTRmIn0%3D; expires=Wed, 30-Sep-2026 06:29:36 GMT; Max-Age=155520000; path=/; samesite=lax`

However this cookie is not set by the browser as it's always empty.

[image]

I make the request as follows:

```
axios.get("https://api.example.com/users")
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: May be you set cookie in api.example.com domain?

Comment: if any site could set cookies on a different domain then internet security would be the fevered dream of a madman.

Comment: So I guess `SameSite` should be `none` @apokryfos at least in dev environment?

Comment: Even if `SameSite` is `none` the cookie will be set for the `api.example.com` domain. The `https://api.example.com` is not able to set cookies for `http://127.0.0.1:3000` and `http://127.0.0.1:3000` is not able to read any cookies set by `https://api.example.com`. If you want to share a CSRF token then you need to perform a normal request and put the token in the response body where the receiving host can then store it in a cookie or local storage or wherever. In **that** case any cookies that `https://api.example.com` has set with a `SameSite` policy as `none` will be sent.